# Diferença na tela Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

Estou com um problema no Visual Studio > Windows Forms. Quando habilito o tema clássico do Windows e crio um projeto em C# a tela fica dentro do que eu quero, porém, ao habilitar o modo Aero, o lado direito da tela fico desalinhada.
Logo abaixo está um print da diferença (distância do lado esquerdo difere do lado direito).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esclareça seu problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes para destacar exatamente o que precisa. Do modo como está escrito aqui, é difícil saber exatamente o que você está perguntando. Consulte a página [Como perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para obter ajuda no esclarecimento desta pergunta.

Comment: parece-me que tem a ver com o tamanho do border do form

Answer (score 2):

Isso é comum. Existem diversos fatores que alteram o "tamanho real" do form. Como, por exemplo, as bordas ou até mesmo aquela sombra que fica "atrás" da janela no Windows 10.

O que você pode fazer é trabalhar com funções do sistema operacional para tentar lidar com isso.

Talvez [esta resposta do SO possa te ajudar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16484894/4190610). Como não sei qual seu objetivo, não posso indicar nada mais do que isso.

Comment: Então, precisa fazer algo para manter o mesmo padrão para todos os visuais.

Comment: Não tem como manter padrão magicamente. Você teria que calcular as dimensões o tempo inteiro ou então usar painéis e âncoras.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente você colocando painéis com 6-8 de largura nas bordas evita esse tipo de problema.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, o problema estava no tamanho mínimo e tamanho máximo do Forms.